# Does anyone know what's wrong with my rock paper scissors game?

Tags: python

I'm writing a python rock paper scissors game, and whenever a tie happens at least once, and then the player loses/wins, it prints duplicate messages.

```
import random
optioncomp = 0
print("Welcome to rock, paper, scissors!")


def genbot():
    global optioncomp
    optioncomp = random.randint(1, 3)
    if optioncomp == 1:
        print("Bot chose rock.")

    if optioncomp == 2:
        print("Bot chose paper.")

    if optioncomp == 3:
        print("Bot chose scissors.")

    if optioncomp == 1:
        optioncomp = "r"

    if optioncomp == 2:
        optioncomp = "p"

    if optioncomp == 3:
        optioncomp = "s"


option = input("What would you like? Rock, paper, or scissors?: ")


genbot()


def lose():
    print("You lost :(! Good luck next time!")


def win():
    print("You won! Congratulations on the win!")


def tie():
    global option
    print("It's a tie! Retry!")
    option = input("What would you like? Rock, paper, or scissors?: ")
    genbot()
    tryscan()


def tryscan():
    if option[0] == "r":
        if optioncomp == "r":
            tie()
        if optioncomp == "p":
            lose()
        if optioncomp == "s":
            win()
    if option[0] == "p":
        if optioncomp == "r":
            win()
        if optioncomp == "p":
            tie()
        if optioncomp == "s":
            lose()
    if option[0] == "s":
        if optioncomp == "r":
            lose()
        if optioncomp == "p":
            win()
        if optioncomp == "s":
            tie()


tryscan()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please keep code contained in the question's text, rather than in an external website (as it may become invalid, or blocked to some users)

Comment: Can you post a example output. Not clear about what you mean by duplicate messages

Comment: The problem is with your unnecessary use of recursion.

Answer (score 2):

This is a weird one! Say the user and bot both choose `rock`. Then your code is here:

```
def tryscan():
    if option[0] == "r":
        if optioncomp == "r":
            tie()   # <-- HERE
        if optioncomp == "p":
            lose()
        if optioncomp == "s":
            win()
```

`tie()` is called, which runs the game again. User chooses, say, `scissors`, and bot chooses `paper`; user wins. The win message is printed.

But then `tie()` returns *back* into to the place marked `HERE`. It continues running, and since now `optioncomp == "p"`, the code enters the `if optioncomp == "p"` block and runs `lose()`

A straightforward way to fix this is to replace the chains of `if`s in `tryscan` with `if`-`elif` chains. Then then `tie()` returns, it will not enter another comparison.

Let me know if this made sense :-)

Comment: Could an alternative fix be to replace `tie()` with `return tie()`?

Comment: @Cam yes, i think that would work too

Comment: I tried this fix, but now it doesn't even give an outcome for the responses. It just says "bot chose rock" for example, and the program just ends there.

Comment: @Technot It works for me. Can you post the new non-working code in a comment, perhaps via [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/)?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WWff2g3E

Comment: @Technot I meant to only change the `if`-chains in the `tryscan` function, since that is the function that is problematic.